# Reference/Literature on Eichler integrals

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Has anyone reference or literature advices on Eichler integrals? I want to know what the Eichler integral associated to a modular form is.

It should help to understand [this](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf), page 65, 4th sentence in the second paragraph.

Thank you!